# How to disable glPointParameterfv

Tags: opengl-es, openframeworks, particles

I am making some particle demo with openframeworks(v0.7.4 for iOS).

Sometimes I'd like to change their size by distance,
and it works well with the code like below.

```
ofVboMesh mesh;
mesh.setMode(OF_PRIMITIVE_POINTS);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < debris.size(); i++){
mesh.addVertex(debris[i]);
    mesh.addColor(color_debris[i]);
}
static GLfloat distance[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };//------------------ set vec
glPointParameterfv(GL_POINT_DISTANCE_ATTENUATION, distance);//---- set attenuation
glPointSize(40000);
mesh.draw();
```

But next time when another Particles are drawn, there's no need to change their size by distance. I want to cancel or initialize what I did with glPointParameterfv().

I guess this might be really primitive question, but cannot find way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set it back to the default values, which is 1.0, 0.0, 0.0. Alternatively you could also get the original values before you change them using something like `glGetFloatv(GL_POINT_DISTANCE_ATTENUATION, oldDistance);` and set it back to those after you are finished drawing your particles.

Comment: Thank you Maurice!
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) does not work well but I could solve this with your indication.

    static GLfloat distance_def[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };//this is only for init
    glGetFloatv(GL_POINT_DISTANCE_ATTENUATION, distance_def);//get original parameter
    ofLog(OF_LOG_ERROR, "%f %f %f", distance_def[0], distance_def[1], distance_def[2]);//logged

Original parameter was (1.0, 0.0, 0.0), I feel strange ((1.0, 1.0, 1.0) is much more reasonable), but anyway I got the visual what I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome. The OpenGL documentation said the default was (1). I thought that meant 1,1,1 but maybe I interpreted that wrong. I'll edit my answer.